# Convert code to .EXE using -noexit parameter

Tags: powershell, obfuscation

I want to convert my PowerShell to .EXE in order to obfuscate the code a bit, but I couldn't achieve my goal so far.
I tried with different tools such as PS2exe, powergui, steroids, … and none of them let me add the parameters to the PowerShell command.

```
powershell.exe -noexit -windowstyle hidden -file c:\temp\myscript.ps1
```

Anybody who could give me a tip of how to achieve this? or maybe any other way to obfuscate the code?

Comment: Most of those converters just run and exe that calls the script in the backround. If you really wanted to find the code you still could in some case. There is the [`-EncodedCommand`](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/windows-powershell-cookbook/9780596528492/ch01s08.html) parameter but that is just security through obscurity and can be easily reverse engineered. Would just stop the more lazy ones. What are you trying to prevent? Depending on your end game perhaps you need to look into another language.

Comment: hi Matt, thanks for the answer. I am trying to monitor the USB sticks. My script hooked to the WMI event and check some compliance in the USB. If doesn't comply, I automatically eject it. My problem is I hard code in the powershell some salt I use to calculate a hash.... I know that is not a good practice but so far I dont have any other option. I just wanted to hide it from a normal user, I know a real hacker will get the salt at some point...

Comment: The salt doesn't need to be secret, but you should use different salts for different input values. The purpose of using salts is to render [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) useless.

Comment: That is exactly my issue, I use a fixed salt . I need it to check that a timestamp is not tampered . A kind of symmetric encryption.

Comment: *That is exactly my issue, I use a fixed salt.* Well, fix that then.

Comment: @jacortijo Based on your first comment it sounds like you want to put a file (or similar) on a USB stick to indicate that the USB stick is allowed to be used. Why not just hash whatever you want on the stick and sign the hash (ie "sign the stick")? To be robust you would need to send the hash to a signing server (or similar), but if you are just trying to avoid casual creation of the stick signature you could embed the signing (private) key in your script, possibly obfuscated. To answer OP, you could have the script embedded in exe by PS2exe, et al., execute whatever PS command line you want.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers. to use a fixed salt is a limitation imposed by the company who is developing the kiosk solution. I suggest them to use private-public encription and they refused. In any case if I use a dynamic salt in my code, if my code is not obfuscate, any power user could read the source code , see how the salt is created and create their own valid stamp in USBs.

Comment: @user2460798.that is exactly the business case,users come to the office with their own USB sticks and plug them in the workstations.With this script I will look for the stamp on them,which contains the timestamp of the last scan in the kiosk. if it is more than 24 hours,the USB will be ejected automatically.Thats is why I need a way to avoid a user to create the stamp manually. Public-private keys are refused by the provider.I already tried PS2exe,Sapiens,ISEsteroids,..and all them let you create the EXE but dont support the -noexit -windowstyle hidden parameters,only parameter of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I finally did the trick. Embed code! :)
the ScriptBlock is the key.

```
$sb = {

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA ''Win32_LogicalDisk'' AND TargetInstance.DriveType=2'

        Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -SourceIdentifier RemovableDiskDetection -Action {
            $class = $eventArgs.NewEvent.__CLASS
            $device = $eventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.DeviceID

            $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
            switch ($class)
            {
                __InstanceCreationEvent {
                    $path = $device + '\flag\'
                    Write-Host '*** Checking the existence of the file $path'
                    if (Test-Path -Path $path)
                    {
                        $wshell.Popup('Inserted, device id: $device WITH flag', 0, 'Done', 0x1)

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $wshell.Popup('Inserted, device id: $device WITHOUT flag', 0, 'Done', 0x1)
                    }
                }
                __InstanceDeletionEvent {
                    $wshell.Popup('Removed, device id: $device ', 0, 'Done', 0x1)
                }
           }
        }
}

start-process powershell.exe -argument "-noexit -nologo -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -command $sb"
```

Once I jsut manage to embed the parameters and get a normal ps1 file as result, I used the PS2EXE tool to compile it.

```
.\ps2exe.ps1  -noConsole -inputFile .\magic.ps1 -outPutFile magic.exe
```